# jQuery: scrollbar does not jump to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#retrieve").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "retrieve.php",
            data: null,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#html").html(data, function () {
                    $("#html").scrollTop($("#html").scrollHeight);
                });
            },
            cache: false
        });
    });
});
```

But it does scrolls to bottom. Is any mistake in my code or browser seems not to do what i have given as a task to it ?

Comment: @pXL Its a `div` where data is appended after ajax request is completed.

Answer (score 0):

`.scrollHeight` is a Javascript property - `$("#html")` is a jQuery collection. You can't reference Javascript properties directly on jQuery collections - you need to filter the collection to a single DOM element first, or use a jQuery-based approach.

Try the following:

```
$("#html").scrollTop($("#html").prop("scrollHeight"));
```

or

```
$("#html").scrollTop($("#html")[0].scrollHeight));
```